# Retrieve Data from many-to-many table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, many-to-many, information-retrieval

I'm new to SQL Server. I don't know how I can retrieve data from a many-to-many table.

My tables looks like:

**Hospitals**:

[image]

**Treatments**:

[image]

**hospitals_treatments**:

[image]

How can I view my data like on table `hospital_treatment` but instead of id I want name from respective tables. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT
b.name, c.name
FROM
    Hospital_treatment a
JOIN Hospitals b
    ON a.hospitalshospital_id = b.id
JOIN Treatments c
    ON a.treatmentstreament_id = c.Id
```

Comment: It is throwing error `Invalid object name 'hospitals_treatments'

Comment: I actually had mistaken in table name at the first time. Now i have changed it. But replacing with corrected name also is giving same result. Now my code looks like this: `SELECT
h.name, t.name
FROM
    hospitals_treatments ht
JOIN Hospitals h
    ON ht.hospitalshospital_id = h.hospital_id
JOIN Treatments t
    ON ht.treatmentstreatment_id = t.treatment_id;`

Comment: @Anon, which _"same result"_? At first you did not have any code, then you had exception because if misspelled name.

Comment: @Anon Can you give more specifics? Like a picture of the error and etc.. 

With the statement you give should be alright.

Comment: @Anon if this works please accept the answer thank you :D

Comment: Actually the problem was i had to use database every time i connect to the server, which i didn't thats why the problem was occurring now it's working. Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

Above answer is correct but here is full script if someone got confused with a,b,c shortcuts.

```
SELECT
Hospitals.name, Treatments.name
FROM
    Hospital_treatments
JOIN Hospitals
    ON hospitals_treatments.hospitalshospital_id = Hospitals.id
JOIN Treatments
    ON hospitals_treatments.treatmentstreament_id = Treatments.Id
```